# How do I install pip for python 3.7.11 on CentOS 7

Tags: python, pip, centos

My goal is to install Python 3.7.11 offline on CentOS 7.

First i installed Python 3.7.11 on CentOS 7 by using this official [python package](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3711/)

The install command was

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

The Installation was not the problem. After that I tried to install pip using `yum` but that was for python 2.7.5 or 3.6.8

How do I install pip for Python 3.7.x versions?

This is my /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  119  5월  3 10:21 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  123  5월  3 10:23 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  126  5월  3 10:19 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   95  5월  3 10:19 pip
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  130  5월  3 10:19 pip-20.1.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  113  5월  3 10:19 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096  5월  3 10:19 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  170  5월  3 10:19 setuptools-47.1.0.dist-info
```

As you can see, I have pip.
But if I run `pip --version` or `pip3 --version`, the command is not found.

How can I now install pip for python 3.7.x?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo yum update
 
sudo yum install epel-release python-devel python-setuptools python-pip

# Download get-pip.py: Download the installation script for pip using curl.

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py


sudo python3 get-pip.py
```